# How does instantiating an object in the getter work if the setter is used first?

Tags: initialization, calculator, getter, stanford-nlp, lazy-initialization

I'm working through the Stanford lectures, calculator tutorial. http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/cgi-bin/drupal/downloads-2011-fall

In it he suggests a good technique for creating an instance of a model is to alloc/init in the getter with:

```
- (NSMutableArray *)operandStack
{
    if(!_operandStack) {
        _operandStack = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    return _operandStack;
}
```

However, the first time `[operandStack]` is used is:

```
 [self.operandStack addObject:operandObject];
```

Which, I understand, is using the setter.

I can see that it obviously works (it runs) - but I'm at a loss understanding why if no-ones tried to get anything from `operandStack` yet. Could someone please enlighten me, I've not had any luck with any searches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your misunderstanding seems to stem from the idea that `[self.operandStack addObject:operandObject];` is a "setter" operation. To translate that expression to english:"Send the 'addObject' message to the NSMutableArray returned by the method operandStack, passing it the operandObject object."

This seems to be a dot notation confusion. Dot notation simply resolves to basic function calls. So for example the above code excerpt could be written using the familiar square bracket notation. Like so:

```
[[self operandStack] addObject:operandObject];
```

This form is still perfectly valid, and even preferred by some. In this form it makes it a bit clearer to see that you are actually calling the "getter" function.

Comment: Ah yes, I see. Thankyou very much. I was thinking of it like a variable. Seems I'm missing some fundamental understanding.

Comment: Ok, I think I get that now. I'm now wondering what I would use the setter for in this case, if I'm always getting the array to manipulate it. I understand getters and setters as far as setting and retrieving a variable, but I'm thinking that's a naive understanding now.